# Get model's ModelAdmin "list_display" fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Consider a model called `Person` which has four fields:

- f_name
- l_name
- dob
- something_else

I registered this model on the admin site. In the ModelAdmin class, I specified the list_display` fields like so:

```py
list_display = ["f_name", "l_name", "something_else"]
```

In the `view.py` file, I called the model object using the `apps.get_model()` function from `django.apps`. Now that I have this model object, I want to retrieve the `list_display` fields through this model object. How would I be able do that?

Thanks for reading this awfully presented question and your time, I really appreciate any help.

**EDIT :** I would also like to know how I store the data in a list according to the list_display fields from a queryset. For example:

```py
represented_data = [['John', "Snow", "He died"], ["Arya", "Not Snow", "Killed the king"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example to get ModelAdmin from Model

```
from django.contrib import admin
...

YourModel = apps.get_model('your_app_name','your_model')
your_list_display = admin.site._registry[YourModel].list_display
...
```

and, to get data as a list of lists, you can use the next code:

```
represented_data = list(YourModel.objects.values_list(*your_list_display))
```

Comment: This works great but I'm running into a slight problem.
What if my list_display looks like this:
`list_display = ["full_name", "dob", "something_else"]`

Where `full_name` is a function like so:
`def full_name(self, obj): return f"{obj.first_name} {obj.last_name}"`
This gives me the following error:
"Cannot resolve keyword 'full_name' into field. Choices are: all_the_model_field_choices"

Comment: Is there a way to include the full_name?

Comment: No, in values_list, you only can get a fields, not functions.
In your case, you need get first_name and last_name and work with that in your script.

Comment: I see. Is there a function that returns values (not in a list specifically, any form) on functions too?

Comment: You can make a function in the Query, with annotations. Like YourModel.objects.annotate(full_name=Concat(F(first_name'), Value(' '), F('last_name'), output_field=CharField())).values_list(*['first_name', 'last_name', 'fullname'])